# "Weighted" counts at each combination of factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe):

```
> df=data.frame(from = c("x","y","x","z"), to=c("w","x","w","y"),weight=c(1,1,3,4))
> df
  from to weight
1    x  w      1
2    y  x      1
3    x  w      3
4    z  y      4
```

If I want to calculate how many times an element of column `from` appears in the [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe), I need to use:

```
> table(df$from)
x y z 
2 1 1
```

This is not a weighted sum. Anyway, how could I consider also the column `weight`? E.g. in my example, the correct answer should be:

```
x y z 
4 1 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tapply` and calculate `sum` for each unique value in `from`

```
tapply(df$weight, df$from, sum)

#x y z 
#4 1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `count` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    count(from, wt = weight)
#  from n
#1    x 4
#2    y 1
#3    z 4
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(weight~ from, df)
#from
#x y z 
#4 1 4
```